# Graphical errors: sometimes elements are missing in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card

Sometimes, there are elements missing in Windows - like a graphical error (see picture).
It comes and goes - sometimes this happens when I return back from a locked Windows.
This is what I have done: newest graphic card driver (AMD FirePro W7000 Fire GL V)
It is running under Win 10 1703 64bit.

Does anyone have similar problems?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Do you have the latest drivers installed for your graphics card? This was happening with me with an Nvidia card (Windows 10 v1607 64-bit) but not as bad. Updating the drivers appears to have stopped it from happening.
Perhaps try uninstalling the graphics drivers, reboot, then install them again.

Comment: yes i have done that already